# Is the Kinect 2 Depth Sensor working in the same way as Kinect 1?

Tags: computer-vision, kinect

it already says it in a title and weirdly enough, I'm unable to find information on this.

The Kinect 1 used IR patterns to get depth data for the Kinect, which is shown here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq9SEJxZiUg

There you had the problem that you couldn't combine overlapping images of two Kinects, because the IR fields wouldn't be distinguishable. This could be fixed by letting one Kinect shake, while the other on is still (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2207676.2208335&coll=DL&dl=ACM&CFID=625209301&CFTOKEN=54555397)

Is that still the case for the Kinect 2 or did they change the way this works?

Comment: Hey, I actually know a bit about this, since I was an intern at Microsoft Research when they worked on Shake'n'sense.

In my experience, overlapping Kinect 1 fields of view are definitely worse, but not useless, depending on your application. Where Kinect 1 uses a PrimeSense projected dot pattern, the Kinect 2 uses time-of-flight. I can't say whether two Kinect 2's overlapping matters, though I would suspect it would not be as bad.

What's your application?

Comment: My application is something like this: http://www.zonetrigger.com/articles/Kinect-software/

I want to be able to create trigger zones in a specific room. To get a a picture of the room without any gaps inbetween I would need to stitch the input of the Kinects together.

Comment: Based on my experience, this should be totally fine with Kinect 1s. You don't really need a high-quality depth image.